# Expanding div height

Tags: html, css

I have the following set of 8 boxes. My issue resides in the viewport code of `(min-width: 840px) and (max-width:960px)` which I have included in the snippet. Please view this in that viewport. You will see the boxes will change to 4 rows of 2 columns. When you hover over the boxes you will see that the boxes get moved down to the next row or there is gap under a box. I can't figure out how, when hovering over a box, to make the box's height next to the hovered one to grow, so it matches the height of the hovered box, so the boxes do not get pushed down.

How could I do this?

```css
.blue-box-container {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 /*height: 800px;*/
 height: 100%;
}
.dark-blue-box, .light-blue-box {
 height: 50%;
 width: 25%;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
}
.dark-blue-box{
 background-color: #45a5ba;
}
.light-blue-box {
 background-color: #8fc9d6;
}
.dark-blue-box:hover, .light-blue-box:hover {
 background-color: #a10085;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.dark-blue-box:hover .insideBoxWrap, .light-blue-box:hover .insideBoxWrap {
 padding: 8% 12%;
}
.dark-blue-box:hover .home-icon img, .light-blue-box:hover .home-icon img {
 height: 86px;
 width: 86px;
} 
.dark-blue-box:hover .box-title, .light-blue-box:hover .box-title {
 color: #FFF;
}
.dark-blue-box:hover .box-description, .light-blue-box:hover .box-description {
 display: none;
}
.dark-blue-box:hover .box-description-hover, .light-blue-box:hover .box-description-hover {
 display: block;
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 padding-top: 20px;
}
.insideBoxWrap {
 /*padding: 150px 18%;*/
 padding: 30% 18%;
}
.box-title {
 color: #307382;
 font-size: 3em;
}
.box-description {
 padding-top: 15px;
 color: #307382;
 font-size: 1.6em;
}
.box-description-hover {
 display: none;
}
.dark-blue-box:nth-child(5), .dark-blue-box:nth-child(7){
 background-color: #8fc9d6;
}
.dark-blue-box:nth-child(5):hover, .dark-blue-box:nth-child(7):hover{
 background-color: #a10085;
}
.light-blue-box:nth-child(6), .light-blue-box:nth-child(8){
 background-color: #45a5ba;
}
.light-blue-box:nth-child(6):hover, .light-blue-box:nth-child(8):hover{
 background-color: #a10085;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 840px) and (max-width:960px) {

.blue-box-container {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
.dark-blue-box, .light-blue-box {
 height: 33%;
 width: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
}
.dark-blue-box:hover .box-description-hover, .light-blue-box:hover .box-description-hover {
 display: block;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 padding-top: 10px;
}
.dark-blue-box:hover .box-description-hover, .light-blue-box:hover .box-description-hover {
 display: block;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 padding-top: 3%;
 clear: both;
}
.dark-blue-box:hover .insideBoxWrap, .light-blue-box:hover .insideBoxWrap {
 padding: 3% 6%;
}
.dark-blue-box:hover .box-title, .light-blue-box:hover .box-title {
 padding-top: 7%;
}
.dark-blue-box:nth-child(3){
 background-color: #8fc9d6;
}
.light-blue-box:nth-child(4){
 background-color: #45a5ba;
}
.dark-blue-box:nth-child(3):hover, .light-blue-box:nth-child(4):hover{
 background-color: purple;
} 
.dark-blue-box:nth-child(5){
 background-color: #45a5ba;
}
.light-blue-box:nth-child(6){
 background-color: #8fc9d6;
}
.insideBoxWrap {
 padding: 10% 30px;
}
.box-title {
 font-size: 2em;
}
.box-description {
 padding-top: 5px;
 font-size: 1.1em;
}
  }
```

```html
<div class="blue-box-container"><div class="dark-blue-box fadeBlock">
   <div class="insideBoxWrap">
    <div class="home-icon"><img src="/icons/screen6.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="box-title">Brand Strategy</div>
    <div class="box-description">Digital Roadmap</div>
    <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs
    fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfsfdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs</div>
   </div>
   </div><div class="light-blue-box fadeBlock">
   <div class="insideBoxWrap">
    <div class="home-icon"><img src="/icons/web2.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="box-title">Development</div>
    <div class="box-description">That Outperforms</div>
    <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs
    fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfsfdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs</div>
   </div>
   </div><div class="dark-blue-box fadeBlock">
   <div class="insideBoxWrap">
    <div class="home-icon"><img src="/icons/tie13.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="box-title">Visual Identity</div>
    <div class="box-description">That Is Timeless</div>
    <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs
    fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfsfdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs</div>
   </div>
   </div><div class="light-blue-box fadeBlock">
   <div class="insideBoxWrap">
    <div class="home-icon"><img src="/icons/hand256.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="box-title">Interactivity</div>
    <div class="box-description">For Engagement</div>
    <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs
    fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfsfdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs</div>
   </div>
   </div><div class="dark-blue-box fadeBlock">
   <div class="insideBoxWrap">
    <div class="home-icon"><img src="/icons/windows10.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="box-title">Responsive</div>
    <div class="box-description">Web Layout</div>
    <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs
    fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfsfdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs</div>
   </div>
   </div><div class="light-blue-box fadeBlock">
   <div class="insideBoxWrap">
    <div class="home-icon"><img src="/icons/gear49.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="box-title">Ecommerce</div>
    <div class="box-description">Conversion Focused</div>
    <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs
    fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfsfdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs</div>
   </div>
   </div><div class="dark-blue-box fadeBlock">
   <div class="insideBoxWrap">
    <div class="home-icon"><img src="/icons/news1.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="box-title">Dynamic</div>
    <div class="box-description">Functionality</div>
    <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs
    fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfsfdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs</div>
   </div>
   </div><div class="light-blue-box fadeBlock">
   <div class="insideBoxWrap">
    <div class="home-icon"><img src="/icons/conversion.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="box-title">Conversion</div>
    <div class="box-description">Increase Results</div>
    <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs
    fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfsfdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs</div>
   </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: since you are increasing the padding on hover the box takes extra space and then the other one moves down since there is no enough space for it to fit in

Comment: @Reddy Right, but is there anyway to adjust the other boxes for when this happens?

Comment: I think you got a correct answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `display:flex` and `min-height` instead `height` .

```css
.blue-box-container {
  position: relative;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*height: 800px;*/
  min-height: 100%;
}
.dark-blue-box,
.light-blue-box {
  min-height: 50%;
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
}
.dark-blue-box {
  background-color: #45a5ba;
}
.light-blue-box {
  background-color: #8fc9d6;
}
.dark-blue-box:hover,
.light-blue-box:hover {
  background-color: #a10085;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dark-blue-box:hover .insideBoxWrap,
.light-blue-box:hover .insideBoxWrap {
  padding: 8% 12%;
}
.dark-blue-box:hover .home-icon img,
.light-blue-box:hover .home-icon img {
  height: 86px;
  width: 86px;
}
.dark-blue-box:hover .box-title,
.light-blue-box:hover .box-title {
  color: #FFF;
}
.dark-blue-box:hover .box-description,
.light-blue-box:hover .box-description {
  display: none;
}
.dark-blue-box:hover .box-description-hover,
.light-blue-box:hover .box-description-hover {
  display: block;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.insideBoxWrap {
  /*padding: 150px 18%;*/
  padding: 30% 18%;
}
.box-title {
  color: #307382;
  font-size: 3em;
}
.box-description {
  padding-top: 15px;
  color: #307382;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}
.box-description-hover {
  display: none;
}
.dark-blue-box:nth-child(5),
.dark-blue-box:nth-child(7) {
  background-color: #8fc9d6;
}
.dark-blue-box:nth-child(5):hover,
.dark-blue-box:nth-child(7):hover {
  background-color: #a10085;
}
.light-blue-box:nth-child(6),
.light-blue-box:nth-child(8) {
  background-color: #45a5ba;
}
.light-blue-box:nth-child(6):hover,
.light-blue-box:nth-child(8):hover {
  background-color: #a10085;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 840px) and (max-width: 960px) {
  .blue-box-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .dark-blue-box,
  .light-blue-box {
    min-height: 33%;
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .dark-blue-box:hover .box-description-hover,
  .light-blue-box:hover .box-description-hover {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  .dark-blue-box:hover .box-description-hover,
  .light-blue-box:hover .box-description-hover {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding-top: 3%;
    clear: both;
  }
  .dark-blue-box:hover .insideBoxWrap,
  .light-blue-box:hover .insideBoxWrap {
    padding: 3% 6%;
  }
  .dark-blue-box:hover .box-title,
  .light-blue-box:hover .box-title {
    padding-top: 7%;
  }
  .dark-blue-box:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #8fc9d6;
  }
  .light-blue-box:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: #45a5ba;
  }
  .dark-blue-box:nth-child(3):hover,
  .light-blue-box:nth-child(4):hover {
    background-color: purple;
  }
  .dark-blue-box:nth-child(5) {
    background-color: #45a5ba;
  }
  .light-blue-box:nth-child(6) {
    background-color: #8fc9d6;
  }
  .insideBoxWrap {
    padding: 10% 30px;
  }
  .box-title {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
  .box-description {
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="blue-box-container">
  <div class="dark-blue-box fadeBlock">
    <div class="insideBoxWrap">
      <div class="home-icon">
        <img src="/icons/screen6.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="box-title">Brand Strategy</div>
      <div class="box-description">Digital Roadmap</div>
      <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfsfdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="light-blue-box fadeBlock">
    <div class="insideBoxWrap">
      <div class="home-icon">
        <img src="/icons/web2.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="box-title">Development</div>
      <div class="box-description">That Outperforms</div>
      <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfsfdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dark-blue-box fadeBlock">
    <div class="insideBoxWrap">
      <div class="home-icon">
        <img src="/icons/tie13.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="box-title">Visual Identity</div>
      <div class="box-description">That Is Timeless</div>
      <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfsfdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="light-blue-box fadeBlock">
    <div class="insideBoxWrap">
      <div class="home-icon">
        <img src="/icons/hand256.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="box-title">Interactivity</div>
      <div class="box-description">For Engagement</div>
      <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfsfdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dark-blue-box fadeBlock">
    <div class="insideBoxWrap">
      <div class="home-icon">
        <img src="/icons/windows10.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="box-title">Responsive</div>
      <div class="box-description">Web Layout</div>
      <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfsfdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="light-blue-box fadeBlock">
    <div class="insideBoxWrap">
      <div class="home-icon">
        <img src="/icons/gear49.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="box-title">Ecommerce</div>
      <div class="box-description">Conversion Focused</div>
      <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfsfdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dark-blue-box fadeBlock">
    <div class="insideBoxWrap">
      <div class="home-icon">
        <img src="/icons/news1.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="box-title">Dynamic</div>
      <div class="box-description">Functionality</div>
      <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfsfdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="light-blue-box fadeBlock">
    <div class="insideBoxWrap">
      <div class="home-icon">
        <img src="/icons/conversion.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="box-title">Conversion</div>
      <div class="box-description">Increase Results</div>
      <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfsfdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is all you did `display:flex;  flex-wrap:wrap;` and the `min-height: 100%;` to the `blue-box-container` ? I tried this because I didn't see anything else different and it doesn't seem to be working like yours. I added an image to my question.

Comment: @Paul in the mediaqueries i turned height to min-height too :)

Comment: @Paul around line 1696 you did not turn height to min-height ...:( do the full edit/correction :) cause it looks like you did not either in the media querie

Comment: Great. That fixed that issue, but my media query still doesn't resize. I believe I have all the code the same as yours now.

Comment: line 1696, 2728, 3114, 3529,  ?  (open the search box in your editor and look for `.dark-blue-box,` to start with

Comment: Nevermind, sorry I put it in the wrong media query! Sorry for the noob mistake. Thanks for all of your help, much appreciation!

Comment: @Paul it happens to all of us :)